# Android APP, crashes Catlog provided, Thread exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I started on my android app again, and now it shows this error below. I can provide any information needed to fix the problem.

> 05-12 12:26:30.858    3799-3845/amh.communication.testapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: amh.communication.testapp, PID: 3799
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
>               at java.util.ArrayDeque.removeFirst(ArrayDeque.java:248)
>               at java.util.ArrayDeque.remove(ArrayDeque.java:413)
>               at amh.communication.testapp.MainActivity$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:970)
>               at amh.communication.testapp.MainActivity$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:628)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: According to the exception stack trace that you posted, The exception was thrown because your program tried to `.remove()` an element from an empty `Deque` on line 970 of your MainActivity.java.

Comment: great , i will look into it.

Comment: I made if(object.length!=0){ do } , now I have new error this is the Caused by

            at amh.communication.testapp.MainActivity$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:971)
            at amh.communication.testapp.MainActivity$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:628)

Comment: they look the same... my bad I will do more work on the error

Comment: @jameslarge thanks for the help , got it running , but I have other small question, how do I check if an array of objects is empty or not. Thanks =)

Comment: If it's an array, you can check `a.length == 0`.